# Renaming a tab in javascript tabContainer

Tags: javascript, tabs, title, tabcontainer, dijit.layout

Does anyone know how to update the title of a selected tab using the `dijit.layout.TabContainer`?

I am able to retrieve the current title using `this.tc.getChildren()[tabIndex].title`, but trying to set it as `this.tc.getChildren()[tabIndex].title = newTabTitle` does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit, I verified that

```js
this.tc.getChildren()[tabIndex].set("title",newTabTitle);
```

does the trick!

I hope this helps out anyone else having this same issue in the future!